# How To Show Scrollbar Always On UICollectionView

Tags: ios, xcode, scrollbar, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView added to a UIView in an app I am working on.  Displayed in the UICollectionView I have a set of images pulled from Core Data.  The vertical scrolling works fine but the scrollbar does not display until the user touches the UICollectionView.

How can I make sure the scrollbar at the right is always visible so that an indication is given to the user that it is scrollable?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't make them always visible. Instead, you can flash them once, when the user is first presented with the collection view to notify them, that this view can be scrolled.

Since `UICollectionView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView` you can do this:

```
[myCollectionView flashScrollIndicators];
```

Check out the Settings app for instance. When you go to a settings list that is longer then the screen, the scroll indicator is flashed once.

Comment: `UIScrollView` is the same way.

Comment: I had to put this viewDidAppear to see it I’m action.

Answer (score 5):

FYI for Swift:

```
myCollectionView.flashScrollIndicators()
```

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work for me on iOS 16, I had to create a subclass of UICollectionView and layoutSubviews. And then set the flag where you want the scrollbar flashed, like reloadData

```
  class FlashScrollBarCollectionView: UICollectionView {

     var flashScrollBar = false
     override func layoutSubviews() {
         super.layoutSubviews()
         if flashScrollBar {
             flashScrollIndicators()
             flashScrollBar = false
         }
     }

     override func reloadData() {
         flashScrollBar = true
         super.reloadData()
     }
  }
```