# Make scrollbar always visible on UiCollectionview?

Tags: ios, scrollbar

I have added the following method

[myCollectionView flashScrollIndicators];

But it is not showing scrollbar continuously.
I want to show scrollbar always visible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Show Scrollbar Always On UICollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16551122/how-to-show-scrollbar-always-on-uicollectionview)

Comment: @SanketBhavsar We have used that method but unable to resolve this.

Comment: Please read the answer carefully. It is clearly stating that showing scrollbar continuously is not possible.

Comment: @SanketBhavsar I know but any possibility like custom view